# Read the Audio Files

Tags: android

Can someone tell me how to specify the path to read audio files in bytes.I have been able to list the songs from the sd card in list view. Also i have read the audio file that is present in the raw folder into bytes. However I am not able to specify the path to read the selected song from the list view.

Following is my code:

```
  String[] proj = {
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                   MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                   MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE 
                  };
            musiccursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,proj, null, null, null);
            count = musiccursor.getCount();
            musiclist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneMusicList);
            musiclist.setAdapter(new MusicAdapter(getApplicationContext()));

            musiclist.setOnItemClickListener(musicgridlistener);
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            //To read audio file in bytes
            InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.Audio);

            DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data));
//Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
            {
                  System.gc();
                  TextView tv = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
                  String id = null;
                  if (convertView == null) 
                  {
                        music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
                        musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);

                        id = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                        music_column_index = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE);
                        musiccursor.moveToPosition(position);

                        id += " Size(KB):" + musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
                        tv.setText(id);
                  } 
                  else
                        tv = (TextView) convertView;
                  return tv;
            }
```

Here I am reading a file that has been placed in the raw folder. However I need to read a  audio file that has been selected in the list and i dont know how to reference it.

Comment: which adapter you are using to show data in ListView?

Comment: Any Help? Will be appreciable